# Banshee 2.0 upgrade not available

Tags: banshee, synaptic

**NOTE: Problem *solved***

**Original question:**

> I have added the Banshee Stable PPA to
>   my list of Software Sources.
>
> Launchpad says that 2.0 has been built
>   and it is available.
>
> The problem is that the version
>   synaptic will install is 1.9.6 (I have
>   the Unstable PPA enabled too) where
>   2.0 > 1.9.6.
>
> BTW I am running elementary OS jupiter
>   (which is based of Maverick)

**ANSWER : Launchpad failed to build for Maverick, Lucid, and Karmic**

Comment: Have you tried updating before you upgrade: `sudo apt-get update` ?  Maybe your local package list is out of date...?

Comment: Yes, I ran "sudo apt-get update" in a terminal.

Comment: what architecture are you on?

Comment: I am using 32-bit.

Comment: Oops, I did not see that the maverick, lucid, and karmic builds failed. :8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maverick, Lucid, and Karmic builds failed.

Comment: please update your question with this information, the answers are for answers, thanks!

Comment: Ahh, good catch.  You should probably mark this as the "best answer" because I doubt you're going to get a better one. :)

Comment: @MichaelMS I have to wait 2 days.